# Inheritance and constructor definition in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, default-constructor

I have a base class and the derived one:

```
class Neuron 
{
    protected:
        double input;
        double output;
};

class InputNeuron : public Neuron
{
    public:
        InputNeuron();
};
```

The default constructor of the derived class is defined as follows

```
InputNeuron::InputNeuron() : input(0.0), output(0.0) {}
```

The problem is:
The initializations of input and output are faulty.

My goal here is benefit from inheritance to avert redeclaring input and output in derived classes. However, in the current state, the use of those members raise a message: `input is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class InputNeuron`, message I can't seem to derive information from.

Comment: Does it mean if I want the derived classes to be default-constructed differently, there is no other solution than adding the common class members to each of the derived classes?

Comment: No, see my answer. Given sufficiently low-level protected constructors of the base, the derived classes should be able to initialize the base in any which way they like.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but an `InputNeuron` having a data member named `output` seems odd. Not to say that it's wrong...

Comment: Yes, I admit. Choices, choices. I could add some preprocessing in that object, however inelegant it may seem. As you can imagine, there's room for improvement in both efficiency and design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class constructor can only initialize the (direct) data members of the class; it does not initialize base class data members. Instead, you need to use a base class constructor for that. You will need to define an appropriate base constructor first. If you only want derived classes to use it, make it `protected`:

```
class Neuron 
{
    protected:
        Neuron(double i, double o) : input(i), output(o) {}
    private:
        double input;
        double output;
};

class InputNeuron : public Neuron
{
    public:
        InputNeuron() : Neuron(0, 0) {}
        //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

(You *could* also retain your protected base data members and then *assign* to them in the bodies of the derived constructors, but that's not good style, since it's best to initialize variables immediately with their intended value.)